# Rotate Animation speed

Tags: android, animation, duration, linear-interpolation, rotateanimation

I want my animation to only spin for one rotation. Everytime I adjust the duration it just spins at the same speed for longer/slower. Where am I going wrong?

> ```
> private static final float ROTATE_FROM = 0.0f;
> private static final float ROTATE_TO = -10.0f * 360.0f;
> protected RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO,
>                                         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
>                                         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
> r.setDuration(5000);     
> r.setRepeatCount(0);
> r.setInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
> r.setAnimationListener(AndroidVideoPlayer.this);        
> favicon.startAnimation(r);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the -10.0f that was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is `repeatCount`

```
r.setRepeatCount(0)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatCount(int)

From the documentation:

> Sets how many times the animation should be repeated. If the repeat
>   count is 0, the animation is never repeated. If the repeat count is
>   greater than 0 or INFINITE, the repeat mode will be taken into
>   account. The repeat count is 0 by default.

Or are you saying that the animation continues to rotate for whatever `duration` you set?  (i.e., you set it for 5000 it rotates for 5 seconds even if it overshoots the "end"). What if you set that value to less than the amount of time it takes to rotate your animation?

In that case it's probably your `LinearInterpolator` that's animating for a constant rate of change. You could maybe print the value of `computeDurationHint()` to see if the application is able to guess how long the duration should be.

P.S. What are your `ROTATE_FROM` and `ROTATE_TO` values?

Comment: Hi, I have that in there, I don't want it to repeat only spin once

Comment: I added my values. I am also guessing this is an interpolator issue!

Comment: Well now that I see your values, is that `-10.0f` in the `ROTATE_TO` a typo? I haven't tried that but it seems a little off -- maybe it's multiple times around. Like in snowboarding.  Anyway, add a followup comment if you figure out what fixed it, that way the next person that happens upon the page will see the answer.